# Using different KeyDown events in different objects but in the same form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, keypress, keydown

I have 2 buttons in one form called "button1" and "button2" I have the following code for both of my buttons :

```
   Private Sub Button2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button2.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyData
        Case (Keys.F5)
            MsgBox("F5 in button 2")
        Case (Keys.F6)
            MsgBox("F6 in button 2")
        
    End Select


End Sub


Private Sub Button1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F9) Then
        MsgBox("F9 in button 1")
    End If
End Sub
```

With this code i'm trying activate two different buttons with different keys from the keyboard in the same form.
The problem is that when I try to push the different keys of the different objects only one of them is registering the event.

Example: By deafult I think button 2 is activated so everytime i press f5 and f6 the proper message display with no problem but when press the f9 key is not actually triggering the other event of button 1. I have to click the buttons separately to activate them and then the events register properly .

it's possible to have both of them activated at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written 2 different `KeyDown` events, so if the active control is button2, F5 and F6 will work. if the active control is button1, F9 will.

set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true` and create another KeyDown event for the form like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Form1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F9) Then
        Button1_KeyDown(Me, e)
    End If
   Select Case e.KeyData
        Case (Keys.F5)
           Button2_KeyDown(Me, e)
        Case (Keys.F6)
           Button2_KeyDown(Me, e)
        
    End Select
End Sub
```

Having `KeyPreview = True` the KeyDown will only work for form and not for the buttons, and from there you can call your desired event.

Comment: I see.... then that solved the problem, actually the whole code needed to be inside the general form instead different objects... Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @ImJP, I'm glad your problem is solved. please don't forget to mark as answer if it helped.